# How to pass and use query params in websocket-springBoot with @stomp/stompjs client

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websocket, stomp

WebSocketConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/comp-and-run");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*");
    }
}
```

WSController.java:

```
@Controller
public class WSController {

    @MessageMapping("/message")
    @SendToUser("/comp-and-run/result")
    public String socketTest(Message<String> m) {
        return m.getPayload() + "pong";
    }
}
```

App.jsx:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Client } from '@stomp/stompjs';

function App() {
  const [stc,setStc] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const client = new Client({
        brokerURL: "ws://localhost:8080/ws",
        onConnect: () => {
          client.subscribe("/user/comp-and-run/result", (m) => {
            console.log(m.body);
          });
        }
    });
    client.activate();
    setStc(client);
  },[]);  

  const destroy = () => {
    stc.deactivate();
  };

  const send = () => {
    stc.publish({ destination: "/app/message", body: "ping"});
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={send}>send</button>
      <button onClick={destroy}>destroy</button>
    </> 
  )
}

export default App
```

I want to pass a query paramter to the server while establishing a websocket connection that will be used for some purpose untill the client disconnects. I tried methods given online but for some reason none of them worked.

The closest which helped me is to pass headers while publishing to a channel like so,

App.jsx:

```
const send = () => {
   stc.publish({ destination: "/app/message", body: "ping", headers: {"qp": "1234"});
};
```

But then extracting them in the controller is not trivial.

I also tried modifying the URL: `ws://localhost:8080/ws?qp=1234` and then using

```
public String socketTest(Message<String> m, @RequestParam("qp") String qp);
```

but it fails to capture and bind the param and instead binds with the body.

Modifying the publish URL: `"/app/message?qp=1234"` fails to invoke the controller method itself. Maybe not able to find and map the URL?

Could not find anything in the spring docs also. Path param is mentioned, but none about query params.

Is query params not a thing in the websocket? Do they just use headers for this?

I think modifying the websocket URL and then implementing a ChannelInterceptor or an EventListner might be it but I am not sure how to do that, resources are very scarce, atleast on the spring framework side.

Any help would be appreciated.